# android- prevent dialog with MultiChoiceItems from duplicating data from mySQL database on tap of a button

Tags: java, android, mysql

I have a dialog with `multiChoiceItems` in which its data is gotten from a MySQL database query, then added to a string then added again into an `ArrayList` of type string which is converted into a string array that is used in the `multiChoice` dialog as below:

Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getWorkoutNames();

```
if (data != null) {
    if (data.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            workoutNameTobeAddded = data.getString(0);
            mWorkoutNames.add(workoutNameTobeAddded);

        } while (data.moveToNext());

    }

    //CONVERTING ARRAY_LIST TO A STRING ARRAY
    workoutNameList = mWorkoutNames.toArray(new String[mWorkoutNames.size()]);
}
```

I then check if the `workoutNameList` which is the String array, if its empty, to show a dialog saying that it is so, then else, meaning it has data, to show the names in a dialog with `multiChoiceItems` as below:

```
if(workoutNameList.length<1){

    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Workouts not created")
            .setMessage("Do you want to create a workout?")
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    //Do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    Intent intent=new Intent(Main2Activity.this,NewWorkoutActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }).setCancelable(false);

    dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();

    }
    else {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main2Activity.this);

        builder.setTitle("Select workout(s) to perform");
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(workoutNameList, null, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.Yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        builder.setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }
}
```

This method is called on a tap of a button. So every time it is tapped the code runs and keeps adding the same data to the dialog.How can I prevent this, so that the dialog only shows the names that are in the DB without duplicating themselves and also to check if there is a new name in the DB and add it as well.

Comment: Do you clear your `mWorkoutNames` at any time?

Comment: Hi , no I haven't where should I clear it?

Comment: I'm not sure about your logic but I think one possibility would be right after `Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getWorkoutNames();`

Comment: It worked thank you so much I had forgotten about the clear method

Comment: You should answer it officially at least I get you more rep points

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to clear your `mWorkoutNames` before (re-)populating them after 
`Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getWorkoutNames();`.